# How to change Magento Search URL result

Tags: regex, magento, search

i need to change the search url for magento.

```
How can i redirect from catalogsearch/result/?q=test to search/test
```

The rule for .htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [QSA,P,NC]
```

I tried to change catalogsearch/result on Helper but i cannot find ?q=.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

q is the name of the input field for the search. You could change that in the template where your input field is defined.

Comment: if i change the root for action get and put there search this is getting /search/?q=test what i need is to redirect catalogsearch/result/?q=test to search/test if i write search/test in url is working perfect, the only problem is that i cannot redirect by default on request.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. The Magento search request is just a simple submitted form. It won't be possible to just "change" that behavior. You have to add some JavaScript code to your form, that onsubmit does a relocate to your new url instead of usually submitting the form and adding the fields as query parameters.

Comment: to complicated to change the url destination and put the query at the end.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know any other way to call a dynamic url without using JS and I doubt there is one.